# Magento2 want to override final_price.phtml file

Tags: php, overriding, magento2

I am using magento2 and  want to override file

**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

I try to copy in my theme

**/app/design/frontend///Magento_Catalog/templates/product/final_price.phtml**

but its not working, file still from /vender folder

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You will have to add final price on below path, then it will work correctly,

app/design/frontend/PACKAGENAME/THEMENAME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Comment: A little late, but this deserves more love.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add final price on below path, then it will work correctly,

/app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

/app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml